# Jacorb/Tao Interoperability

Tags: tao, jacorb

I have Appl A which is JacORB client and Appl B is the TAO server .

Details of execution:

a)       Appl A initially creates the object_reference for server process (Appl B) using its corbaloc URL and maintains this reference in a map for subsequent usage. 
        This mean the same object reference is used for all the corba calls on Appl B.

b)       Appl A calls a inventory  method on the narrowed object reference of Appl B as created above.

c)       On Server side (TAO), the servant completes the request and sends the reponse.

d)       After a long time (I think after the timeout interval)on the Jacorb Client side I get an exception :

```
     org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe
    at org.jacorb.orb.giop.ReplyPlaceholder.getInputStream(ReplyPlaceholder.java:133)
```

. 
e)       In case, before the above request times out, if same query is again made on the server, ( uses same connection object ), both  responses are received ,processed properly

Any idea how to proceed in this case ?
My guess is that socket buffer is waiting for a flush ,thats why it always works the second time
Any idea how to force the flush on the connection object ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the TAO side with -ORBDebugLevel 10 and see what the ORB prints as messages. Your TAO version is pretty old, check TAO 2.0.3 which you can download from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu